# Discord message gets deleted until a new user responds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make it when a user sends a message until someone else sends a message there message gets deleted so 1 person can't send a message twice until someone else sends. but i don't know how to do it maybe by check what the last message was on the channel and the message author?

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!oChannel.includes(message.channel.id)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(/ +/);

  const { author, member } = message;

  if (!message.guild) return;
  if (author.bot) return;
  if (args.length === 3) {
    message.reply('Thanks, wait until other people continue')
      .then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
  } else {
    if (!oChannel.includes(message.channel.id)) return;
    if (message.deletable) message.delete({ timeout: 500 })
    message.reply('Please write 3 words !')
    .then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }))
  }
})

client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  if (!oChannel.includes(newMessage.channel.id)) return;
  if(newMessage.content != oldMessage) {
    if (newMessage.deletable) newMessage.delete({ timeout: 500 })
    newMessage.reply('Edit not allowed !')
      .then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }))
  }
})
```

this is my code so far this is like a three word story code now this code does is when someone sends a message in a channel that longer or shorter than three words it deletes it and also makes it so people can't edit message but

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
Just filter `message.channel.messages.cache` to skip bot messages and get the last element

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!oChannel.includes(message.channel.id)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(/ +/);

    const { author, member } = message;

    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (author.bot) return;
    if (args.length === 3) return message.reply('Thanks, wait until other people continue').then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }));
    let previousMessage = message.channel.messages.cache.filter((m) => !m.author.bot).last();
    if (previousMessage.author.id === message.author.id) {
        message.channel.send('No no no').then((msg) => {
            msg.delete({
                timeout: 2000,
            });
        });
    }
});
```